# !pip install nltk -> permission denied

Tags: apache-spark, ibm-cloud, nltk, jupyter, data-science-experience

I'm trying to install nltk with the following notebook command:

```
!pip install nltk
```

However, that throws the following error:

```
error: could not create '/usr/local/src/bluemix_ipythonspark_141/notebook/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk': 
Permission denied
```

How can I install nltk from the Jupyter notebook?  Note that the spark environments on bluemix can only be accessed via the notebook.  There isn't she'll access to the environment.

Comment: You don't have the admin right

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the question is about IPython notebooks on **Bluemix**, the following suffices:

```
!pip install --user nltk
```

There is no need for manipulating `sys.path`.

Comment: I added the sys path code because originally it failed to load the nltk module without it.  I have just tried again and it works fine without it!

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to install from the notebook as follows:

```
!pip install --user nltk
```

Then in the next cell enter:

```
import os
says.path.append(os.getenv('HOME')+'/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages')
import nltk
```

---

Update: you shouldn't have to manipulate the sys.path as stated in the accepted answer.

Comment: That path doesn't work for me.
`os.getenv('HOME')` returns:
`'/gpfs/fs01/user/myusername'`


while my module installation went into 
`/gpfs/global_fs01/sym_shared/YPProdSpark/user/myusername`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the actual issue is a permission issue or something else. 
If you have sudo access, you can try running the above command with a sudo prefix to it and see if it fixes it.