# Python script using spark library at Bluemix

Tags: python, apache-spark, jupyter-notebook, ibm-cloud

I am trying to write python script to call spark library at Bluemix platform. Would you mind advise the flow?

I have created Apache Spark Analytic Service at Bluemix, and open a iPython Notebook. However, I can't install new python package using `!pip install <package>`

And suppose I have solved this issue, I would like that it works like an application that I can make it continuously at background. Is it possible?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34031360/pip-install-nltk-permission-denied/34036374#34036374

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also, you can do it another way:

First find home dir: 
  `print os.environ["HOME"]`
    Then install module to this directory:  `!pip install <package> -t 'your home directory'`

Append path to directory:

```
 import sys, os      
sys.path.append("".join([os.environ["HOME"]]))
```

Finally import module:        `import <package>`

Answer (score 3):

By default, `pip` installs into system directories. You do not have permission to do that. Instead you need to include the `--user` pip option to install it for your apache spark service tenant only. For future reference, take a look at the [documentation for 3rd-party libraries](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/AnalyticsforApacheSpark/index.html#importing_libraries).

re: "an application that I can make it continuously at background". Well, in an IPython notebook, you can write code that runs however long you want. In fact, you can close the browser page for such a notebook and the notebook kernel will continue to stay alive on the server side; you can explicitly shutdown kernels or reopen the notebook page later if you want.